# Convert Dense_Rank Oracle to PostgresSQL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, max, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a select statement that contains a dense_rank function written in Oracle but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it compatible for postgressql (v11.x)

```
SELECT facility_id_fk, max(inspection_date) as last_inspection,
               max(inspection_type) keep (dense_rank first order by inspection_date desc) as inspection_type
FROM facility_inspections
GROUP BY facility_id_fk
```

This query gives me the last inspection and what type that last inspection was:

```
-------------------------------------------------
facility id | inspection date | inspection type 
-------------------------------------------------
93              04/28/2020        FULL
94              04/28/2020        LIMITED
-------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried the following but it leaves out the inspection type description which I need, and still provides duplicates and looking at the rank column, it looks like its ranking all inspection in the table and not for a specific facility

```
SELECT facility_id_fk, max(inspection_date) as last_inspection,
      dense_rank () OVER (
           PARTITION BY inspection_type
           ORDER BY inspection_date DESC
           ) rank_order
FROM facility_inspections
GROUP BY facility_id_fk, inspection_date, inspection_type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Postgres, you can do this with handy extension `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (facility_id_fk) *
from facility_inspections
order by facility_id_fk, inspection_date desc
```

If you were to do this with window functions, which are much more portable than vendor specific syntaxes such as Oracle's `keep` or Postgres' `distinct on`, you could phrase the query as:

```
select *
from (
    select f.*, row_number() over(partition by facility_id_fk order by inspection_date desc) rn
    from facility_inspections f
) f
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB - This almost got me there. I just had to account for null values (I guess Oracle did it automatically) and narrow the number of columns returned. Thanks so much